# Load DNG/CR2 RAW Images within VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is it possible to load RAW DNG and/or CR2 Image sequences within Blender VSE? Might there be an addon available?

Update:
[Link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57208/how-to-develop-a-vse-file-format-importer-for-dng-cr2-image-files/57245#57245)

Comment: Welcome to the site, Chris. You might want to take the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help). Meantime, [this page](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/files/image_formats.html) lists the file format types supported to Blender. One cannot say that there will not be, at some point, support for Canon (~.cr2) or Adobe negative (~.dng) files added, but they don't seem to be supported at this time.

Comment: [DNG + CR2 does work - see how!](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57208/how-to-develop-a-vse-file-format-importer-for-dng-cr2-image-files/57245#57245)

Comment: @ brasshat - do you think we can add this to the actual feature list?
[sambler's git patch] (https://gist.github.com/sambler/05afb5d61f8a16b5a58dd35cea0ca927)

Comment: Although you can be tricked into thinking that Blender is seeing an image in the DNG as they can be created with embedded jpegs. Which Blender can find and read. Of course they are no use to you for wide DR work.

Comment: Thanks 3pointedit for pointing this out. Sambler already talked about it on the other thread.. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57208/how-to-develop-a-vse-file-format-importer-for-dng-cr2-image-files/57245#57245

Comment: Chris, adding anything to the feature list is above my paygrade.

Comment: Hi brasshat, thanks :) don't worry; I was more thinking of the feature request list... For now I'm stuck at building blender from source; so this is a little problem i need to overcome first. After that I'll try Sambler's advice.
So, for me it will work out this way; at least with cr2 files. DNG I have to find a way of simple removing the thumbs (if there are any)

Answer (score 2):

No, DNG is not supported. Decode first.

Comment: Any clue where to start developing these? So, if it is not available yet; maybe we can make it happen ... What do you think, is that even possible?

Comment: DCraw probably would be my advice. But I would also encourage an offline editing process as well.

Comment: Thanks, will look into DCraw. This is just about getting files into Blender; using proxies for offline editing. But without converting the dng/cr2 into another readable format for blender.

Comment: DCraw does DNG, and should handle it.

Comment: What properties do DNG or CR2 have that you want to make use of, that are not available through other image formats  already supported Blender?

Comment: @brasshat - it is not a feature of the file format I'm after; it is more about removing an unnecessary step = converting to a format with the same "feature-set" just to be readable by blender. This step produces a lot of unwanted data; which only purpose is to be "readable" by the software.

Comment: update: I sent a mail to David; the developer of DCraw. So, If anyone has a clue where to start at implementing DCraw into Blender.

Comment: Just write a script to batch your offlines. No need for it to be in Blender.

Comment: @troy_s - thanks. So, this question isn't about creating offlines. I'm aware of these workflows. I'm more after a new solution. Please understand my point, even if you don't :)

Comment: I understand the point very well. As I said, I am unsure why you need anything more than batching your footage to a suitable format.

Comment: It is really just about spending less time + performance on nonsense tasks.
Example: If you are shooting image sequences with a canon you'll have  cr2 files; when you are shooting video "raw" with a blackmagic you will end up with dng files. Now think about how much time + resources are wasted during these batch converts; before even the real work begins ...

Comment: Done plenty of it. You are always batching. Very little difference if you write a Python script that does the exact same thing. As in you can't escape it and it is precisely the same operation in both instances. Did you check if dcraw can decode your particular flavours of DNG?

Comment: Looks like DCraw isn't what I'm after. So I don't want to decode anything; instead I'd like to load the RAW directly, without any processing what-so-ever.

Comment: Sorry guys; you don't seem to understand ... this isn't about any feature set; this is about saving resources and time!

Comment: I understand very well. Shot a few things. I answered you in the original post, “No, it can't.” No there is no way currently. Use Resolve. It is free.

Comment: Thanks, Resolve won't work on Linux ;/ And they might not release a resolve-lite for linux. so, this doesn't help :) ... nevermind.

Comment: You won't save resources or time... demosaicing directly will give you terrible performance. Two apps that run in Linux will allow you to import a cr2 sequence of images: Natron or Nuke... It is not fast and the performance takes a big hit... At least for editing it makes more sense to transcode to a format that will allow you to edit efficiently, and then maybe re-conform using the original raw files as source for the very final output.

Comment: @cegaton - this is exactly what I want to do, loading RAW - create proxies (offline's) with blender; edit; and go back online for final output. just without the extra step of converting to another format (the step you don't see as time waster)

Comment: [It does work - answered by another stackexchange member](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57208/how-to-develop-a-vse-file-format-importer-for-dng-cr2-image-files/57245#57245)

Answer (score 1):

(Dave Coffin, author of dcraw)

The only resource "wasted" is the disk space occupied by the PPM or TIFF files generated by dcraw, and the time to write and read them. This could be avoided by doing, in the Blender code:

ifp = popen ("dcraw -c (other options) somefile.cr2", "r");

and then reading the PPM or TIFF file from ifp. This would however require Blender to keep track of and allow you to set dcraw options, of which there are many, and they might not be the same for all your photos.

I don't blame the Blender developers for not wanting to get involved with raw photos. Just process them with dcraw.

Comment: Hi Dave, 

thanks for the note. CR2 work straight out of the box. Just need to disable "filters" (VSE) - thanks to Sambler.

 I don't blame them either - I wasn't aware of the fact that it is such deep down the rabbit hole - Thanks to all trying to help