# How to develop a VSE file format importer for DNG + CR2 image files?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, import, file-format

This question isn't about the usual workflow (batch convert to a readable format).
Instead I'm looking for a solution to import DNG + CR2 RAW files directly into blender (without decoding/converting the files again).

Reason: Saving Time and Resources.

Why: Because we all have better things to do besides batching conversions :)

Update: @Sambler : How do you compile blender? With make or make full? Somehow mine can't display the dng-raw. I always get a blank/transparent preview with in a thumbnail resolution (256x). Please read further down below the last comments for more details. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @ all developer - how to start developing this feature?

Comment: DNG SDK + Infos [link](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/digital-negative.html)

Comment: [RAW Format discussion](http://www.openraw.org/node/1482/)

Comment: I doubt strongly that your time is going to be better spent doing demosaicing on the fly... Even if you were to bring a sequence of cr2 or DNGs into the VSE, you'd spend a lot of time caching to get some kind of decent playback... If you are in Linux give Natron (or Nuke) a try, it allows you to import cr2 sequences directly using the default config, but you can also use tuttleOFX's rawreader that gives you a lot more control for the debayering... It is predictably slow... Decoding raw files is not trivial and does require a lot of processing power...

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/57139/2843

Comment: @Samoth; thanks ... I had to start a new question because it somehow was missleading. This isn't about getting the "video job" done. I was more hoping for a developer back-and-forth discussion... so, no offend - just curiosity

Comment: @cegaton - thanks for mentioning the tools. So, I'm not looking for a work-around. I want to make this happen in blender. But it feels like stackexchange is the wrong place for this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off blender seems to read CR2 files without issue, at least with the few samples I downloaded. It could read more data, that is blender loads one of the samples I have in the natural resolution, while the OpenImageIO file viewer automatically rotates it to match the rotation of the camera. Blender's file browser will filter out CR2 files by default but if you disable the filter and select a CR2 file it will read it. Adding CR2 to the list of available file formats is all that is needed here. Once loaded blender says the CR2 file has a TIFF file_format. This would be a minor change that should be accepted as a [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug), test with a variety of files to make sure first.

For DNG, blender only sees the thumbnail - or the thumbnail is found first and mistakenly read as the image data. (if you have one without a thumbnail try it).

From what I have read, DNG is a variation of TIFF/EP so I see two options, first is to adjust blender's [TIFF reading code](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/imbuf/intern/tiff.c), the other is to use OpenImageIO to read DNG files. The image viewer built as part of OpenImageIO can read the sample DNG files that I have found, so this may be a viable option for adding support. For reference using OpenImageIO to read PSD files was [added here](https://developer.blender.org/rB4abb8fde95260e692b3cd5b5b2f8bcd1d1f3be3b), it is possible that this code added for PSD may only need minor changes to also work with DNG.

I'm not sure this will be considered an acceptable bug report as it is adding support for a new file format. You may want to add DNG image support to the [requests page](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Requests) or you could talk to some of the developers at #blendercoders on IRC to see if someone is interested in adding this image support, unless you want to submit a patch for it yourself.

**Update:**

A quick test with just adding to the [file suffix list](https://gist.github.com/sambler/05afb5d61f8a16b5a58dd35cea0ca927) shows that telling blender to use OpenImageIO to open DNG and CR2 files works. Simply adding the file suffixes to the code used for PSD files allows DNG and CR2 files to be opened. As mentioned at the start this brings in CR2 files rotated based on image metadata the same as opening the images using iv. Images opened this way report their `file_format` as JPEG so further work to distinguish DNG and CR2 files from PSD and JPEG will be needed but should be minimal.

Comment: thank you - great answer! I already tried the CR2 with success. Now I'm dealing with the DNG Thumbnail. I'll try your suggested work around. Keep you updated.

Comment: Update: During building I encountered some issues: (http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57249/building-blender-results-in-errror-opencolorio-1-0-9-failed-to-compile-exiting)

Comment: When I load a [DNG Sequence](http://video.blackmagicdesign.com/Shot_4.zip) blender suddenly shuts down. Could you try the footage if it's working on your blender version? Which version do you have? Thanks

Comment: I don't have any trouble with your sequence. This is your first build? are you sure it works with other sequences? I built using the git master from a few days ago (4/7) and have oiio 1.6.15 which was released 6 days ago. Try running blender in gdb and do a backtrace when it stops, this might give a clue as to where it fails.

Comment: thanks for the note. yeah, I'm first build virgin :) Currently I'm having issues related to libtiff4/5.
Do you know how to force selecting a version?
Package libtiff-dev is a virtual package provided by:
  libtiff4-dev 3.9.6-11
  libtiff5-dev 4.0.3-12.3+deb8u1
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'libtiff-dev' has no installation candidate
ERROR! apt-get failed to install requested packages, exiting.
libtiff5-dev 4.0.3-12.3+deb8u1 is installed already, beside libtiff4. libtiff4-dev is not installed.
Any suggestion how to move on?

Comment: @ Sambler; I've tried now original footage from the blackmagic 4k camera (CinemaDNG RAW); but the dng shows "blank". I suppose it does show the empty thumbnail like you referred above. Can you suggest any DNG Stripper which might be handy on this, without converting dng's? Thanks.

Comment: https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/cinemadng/pdfs/CinemaDNG_Format_Specification_v1_1.pdf

5.4 Including Additional Images In The Same DNG Data Set
The DNG dataset may include additional images, such as rendered previews, thumbnails, or reduced resolution
versions, all of which can be used as proxies when editing. A compliant CinemaDNG decoder should ignore these
images.
5.5 Including Additional Tags For Optional TIFF/EP Compliance
The DNG dataset may include additional tags for compliance with TIFF/EP. Compliance with TIFF/EP is not
required....

Comment: Update: After "converting" them from CinemaDNG to DNG with Adobe DNG  Converter the thumbnails can be seen within blender. Even tho I disabled "JPG Preview" within the settings. ... any clue to get the real dng in blender without converting them?
Download DNG for Testing (Not Converted; orignal from Camera): http://wikisend.com/download/968202/AS-BMPC-01_1_2016-07-14_0342_C0017_000004.dng

Comment: The patch I linked to in the update allows blender to open dng files using OpenImageIO, more work needs to be done so that they are properly identified and can be saved as dng, but by adding the file suffixes I am able to open the dng files that I have found so far. To test without a modified blender, try opening the files with `iv` which is the [image viewer app](https://github.com/OpenImageIO/oiio/tree/master/src/) that is part of the oiio source, if `iv` opens it ok then using oiio in blender will get the same result. `iconvert` or `oiiotool` might be able to remove the thumbnails.

Comment: thanks sambler; i'll try the tools ...
you say; you are able to open the dng - have you tried this with the one I uploaded to wikisend? Do you see the actual RAWImage of the DNG?

Comment: after fizzling a bit around with oiiotool I've found the following section: Page 253 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenImageIO/oiio/master/src/doc/openimageio.pdf -> But this is used via python bindings + tga's; any work around to get rid of thumbnails dng without to convert them? I'm a o not able to open the DNG in notepad - can you tell why?

Comment: Yes I have opened the dng sequence you added earlier and the dng file you added today using my patched version of blender. The new one shows as 4032x2192 and is of a tree/bush with power lines in the background.

Comment: So, after doing everything again - just to be sure - DNG won't display. Tho, the Filter changes did work; but I can't see the image.
Steps: 1. get blender source, 2. apply sambler patch, 3. compile, 4. make, 5. start blender (vse) + load test dng = result http://wikisend.com/download/585108/dng.jpg
Have you changed anything else? Or do I need any additional package/addon? Do you see what I'm missing out here ...? thx sambler

Comment: Update: Did you compile blender via "make" or "make full"?

Comment: I can't test "make full" because of a resulting error/conflict with some packages(have to dig deeper to tell you the exact output...)